# Is location manager device dependent?

Tags: android, android-location, android-hardware

I encountered something weird about Android location service. After I finished my first app and tested it on different devices, it worked fine except on one device (local Indian brand - Karbonn A9+ ICS). On the start of app, a service launches which registers for location updates using LocationListener.

On all devices, when the application starts, onLocationChanged is invoked (detected by Toasts) and keeps on at an interval of approx. 1 minute (even if the phone is at single location).

But Karbonn A9+ ICS gives no call to onLocationChanged, in fact, no such call in the next 10-20 minutes. App retrieves location flawlessly on Galaxy Note II, different Xperias, Galaxy Y, Galaxy Tab and many others. Conclusion: location is not retrieved on that particular device.

Why is behavior of the same app different on different Android devices? Is it related to hardware, can cheap hardware be its cause ?

P.S. I used network provider only, the device supports location manager and "Access location using network" is checked.

Comment: Was all GPS things enabled on the other device? Did it have GPS?

Comment: @LiamW - I just made use of network provider, didn't used gps

Comment: I've seen huge time differences getting the user location using GPS (probably hardware) on different devices, but never had that problem with WiFi. Have you tried using another app like Google Maps to see if the same thing happens?

Comment: @Marcelo - Yup, google maps instantly retrieved location on that device but my app was unable to call onLocationChanged on start.